# probability related to uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X$ be the collection of closed interval of the form $[a,1],$ where $a \in [0,1]$ and we fix a real number $t \in [0,1]$. Suppose an element $c$ is randomly drawn from $X$, what is the probability that $t \in c$? My guess is the probability is $t$, but how to prove it rigorously? I know basic real analysis, including elementary measure theory. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $t \in [0,1]$. If $[a,1] \in X$ then $t \in [a,1] \iff  a \le t$. Thus $$P(t \in [a,1]) = P(a \le t).$$ If you are using a uniform distribution this is indeed $t$.

Comment: um, let t=0 and a=.5. So t is in [0,1], but t is not in [.5,1]. I think you might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The probability is not $t$.  the probability is actually $0$.  the interval that you have is continuous, so the probability of picking any number from it is $0$.  For example, the interval from [2,5].  The probability of picking 3 is $0$.  It is not the real analysis answer that I think you are looking for but it might point you in the right direction. I don't think this is uniformly distributed though.

Comment: thank for answering, but why the answer is 0? It is rather counter intuitive. For example, if we fix $t=1$, every $c \in X$ must contain $t$, so the probability in this case is 1. Sorry if i have asked a dump question.

Comment: its not a dumb quesiton.  also are you referring to the real numbers as dedekind cuts? because thats the only way a real number can be inside another real number.  if you look in my example that I gave umberto that might help with half of the issue.  If t is in X, the probability of picking that number is 1/n, where n=infinity, which is zero.  Its like if I was thinking of a number between 1 and infinity, the probability of you picking that number is very low, so practically 0.  Lay it out on a number line to help you think and pick numbers. Have you taken a stats course? that might help